# MSVC : Компиляция и линковка

Tags: компилятор, компиляция

Суть вопроса такова : насколько мне известно, компилятор и линковщик включают в исполняемый файл только те функции, которые в коде вызываются. Мне надо подключить к проекту исходник sqlite, чтобы использовать его функционал, однако только при одном подключении без (!) использования размер исполняемого файла увеличивается на 300 Кб. Почему и за счёт чего? 
Заранее огромное спасибо

Comment: - Это не всегда так и довольно сильно зависит от используемого toolchain'a и, собственно, переданных ему параметров. В общем виде определение unreferenced symbols — это сложная задача из-за наличия инлайнинга, link-time code generation и необходимости инстанцирования шаблонов.

- Так, насколько я знаю, `gcc-arm toolchain` [вообще не умеет strip'ать неиспользуемые символы,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687630/c-c-gcc-ld-remove-unused-symbols) и для получения приемлемого размера приходится все делать руками.

Comment: - В `Visual Studio,` как мне кажется, хороших результатов можно добиться [с помощью опций линковщика `/Gy /OPT:REF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxwfs976(v=vs.110).aspx). Плюс, поскольку `sqlite` является `C` библиотекой, шансы на хороший результат сильно возрастают.

Comment: К сожалению, "потыкав" опции компилятора и линковщика выигрыш в размере файла был, однако очень незначительный:(